# using ssl with aspnet mvc creates a problem when posting data on to the page which is secure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, post

I know there are many posts regarding and it works fine if the action method which i am calling is just a get method, but it fails if the action method has a 'Post' attribute because in the code we do a redirect to the url and not a post

I am using code below...

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Helpers
{
    public class RequiresSSL : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpRequestBase req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
            HttpResponseBase res = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

            //Check if we're secure or not and if we're on the local box
            if (!req.IsSecureConnection && !req.IsLocal)
            {
                var builder = new UriBuilder(req.Url)
                {
                    Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps,
                    Port = 443
                };
                res.Redirect(builder.Uri.ToString());
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the error/problem is?

Comment: I have 2 different pages and one of them is a non secure page. We are trying to get redirected to the secure page from the non secure page using Form Post(method). The above code which i got when googling around is helpful when if we use 'Get' (or just do a regular redirect to a url).

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't figured this out yet `[RequireHttps]` is baked into the framework. Place that attribute on the method you're intending to be secure.